# Set the real cause on error 500 from feignException

Tags: spring-cloud-feign, feign

On my microService I use spring boot feign to ask an RestAPI. This one return an error 404 with this content :

```
{
  "timestamp":"2018-07-10T11:47:47.011+0000",
  "status":404,
  "error":"Not Found",
  "message":"Device not found",
  "path":"/object/fakefake-0000-0000-1111-d7bdce4c6749/measures/first"}
```

I have no fallback on this call so a runtimeException was throwing and i have an error 500. The content of the answare was :

```
{
  "timestamp": "2018-07-10T11:47:47.205+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "IDeviceClient#getFirstMeasure(String,String) failed and no fallback available.",
  "path": "/patients/23/devices/socks/steps"
}
```

It there a way to get the message replace by the real cause (comming from the 404 error on the feign client) ?